# How to center-align the navigation links in responsive menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The menu below is left-aligned. How can we make the links center-aligned (horizontally).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div style="padding-left:16px">
    <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it would be more practical for you to use flex to position such items, rather than wrestling with floats.

To get you started, on `.topnav`, apply:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

On `.topnav a`, you could remove `float: left`. There's other floats you could replace with flex (for more control) as well, but it's up to you if they're useful as-is, and what techniques you want to use. In any case, it seems you probably have to make changes to your @media code as well.